# SSL only partially encrypts on first run

Tags: tomcat, servlets, ssl

We have a Java servlet running on Tomcat and Windows and all database connections are encrypted using SSL.  This works apart from a strange issue on one of the connections (SQL Server) which I do not understand.  I am using WireShark to check the encryption is working but, whenever a new login is performed through the servlet, the FIRST data transfer for this particular connection is only partially encrypting, but if a second or third data transfer to this database connection is made under the same login the entire message is encrypted.

After the login all requests are handled through a token provided by Tomcat.

Why will the first data transfer only be partially encrypting?

EDIT: Here is the entry in Tomcats server.xml file

```
<Connector port="8443"  
 protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" SSLEnabled="true"
  maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25"
  enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true"
  acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
  clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" KeyAlias="ows"
  KeystoreFile="C:\SSLKeys\ows.key" KeystorePass="********" />
```

EDIT 2:  Added relevant JNDI connection

```
<Resource auth="Container"  
driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
factory="org.moss.jdj.dbcp.EncryptedDataSourceFactory" maxActive="100" 
maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/connectionname" 
password="*******" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
url="jdbc:sqlserver://databaseinstallname\db_instancename:2369;   
databaseName=Images;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true" 
username="*******" />
```

Comment: Is it using STARTTLS?

Comment: @EJP I have updated my question to include the server.xml entry and it is using the TLS protocol

Comment: The HTTP Connector configuration is irrelevant. What's relevant is the SQL Server connection you mentioned, and what you sniffed. Did it contain a STARTTLS command?

Comment: @EJP effectively yes. SqlServer uses the "TDS" protocol which starts in clear and upgrades to SSL/TLS if enabled both at the server and in the connector/driver at the client end (for Java the JDBC driver), although it doesn't do this quite the same way as SMTP and FTP etc do STARTTLS, and (last I checked) Wireshark couldn't decode it. AJF: if you look at the pre-encrypted stuff there should be no actual data, only connection metadata like language and transaction-isolation.

Comment: @EJP I apologise for late reply but it was the weekend here.  I have now included the JNDI connection tag from the Tomcat's context.xml file (although had to amend a few details as not allowed to publish to internet).  I am so far not aware of any "STARTTLS" command and never experienced STARTTLS before.  I will google it to find out.  I have answered dave_thompsons comment too.  See below

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I apologise for late response but it was the weekend here.  I have updated the ticket to include JNDI.  Going to investigate the STARTTLS thing that EJP mentioned as never experienced that before.  Regarding the meta data comment, yes, I confirm, the actual retrieved data is encrypted (two thirds of the message is encrypted) and the part that is not encrypted appears to be meta-data.  But the trouble is it includes the servers fully qualified domain name and some information about the SSL certificate.

Comment: @EJP I can add that the application connects to an Oracle database too but does not suffer this issue on that connection.  On that connection every packet is completely encrypted successfully

Comment: @dave_thompson_085  I can add that the application connects to an Oracle database too but does not suffer this issue on that connection.  On that connection every packet is completely encrypted success

Comment: So what was it that you sniffed that wasn't encrypted?

Comment: @EJP If you mean what data I retrieved that wasn't encrypted then I suppose all the retrived data is encrypted.  But what I am concerned about is that the meta data that is not encrypted includes a servers fully qualified domain name and is a potential security risk.  But then the second time this is called over a connection instance it is ALL encrypted.